# How to get index from Mapping array in Solidity/Remix?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, mapping

I can push worker address to mapping with manager address. I try to get manager address like this code.

```
contract Test {

   struct Worker{
        address manager_add;
        address worker_add;
    }

   mapping(address => Worker[]) manager;

   function setWorkerAddress(address worker_add) public{

      manager[msg.sender].push(Worker(msg.sender, worker_add));  // push worker address map with manager address

   }

   function getManagerAddress() public returns(uint){
      return manager[msg.sender].x;  // worker get manage address
   }
}
```

It show error like this.

```
TypeError: Return argument type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) uint256.
  --> contracts/test.sol:21:14:
   |
21 |       return manager[msg.sender][index].manager_add;
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to see the address of the worker's manager. Because you are returning an address, you have to change `function getManagerAddress(uint index) public returns(uint)` to `function getManagerAddress(uint index) public returns(address)`